# Snakemake bash strict mode how to fix "_([^_]+)_"?

Tags: bash, snakemake

Hi I want to use this "_([^_]+)_" expression in my command, I am wondering how to make it fit for Snakemake?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I commonly will put awk scripts into params to prevent any formatting by snakemake in the shell directive.

```
rule one:
    params:
        regex=r'_([^_]+)_'  # note the r
    shell:
        "grep '{params.regex}' "
```

But in this case I think the raw string would be ok without this trick.  It's really useful for scripts like `{sum += $1} END {print sum}` that would otherwise need to have double curly braces `{{sum += $1}} END {{print sum}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain what you mean by *make it fit* and show some code for context... My guess is that you want to use python raw-string formatting to avoid unexpected interpretation? Like (note the `r` before `"""`):

```
rule one:
   ...
   shell:
       r"""
       grep '_([^_]+)_' ...
       """
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I want to use a command from a tool: seqkit split {input}  —by-id --id-regexp "_([^_]+)_"